# How do I create records from a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have an XML file from which I want to create some records. But I am missing something because my code is not saving the record but I am not getting any errors.

MODEL

```
require 'open-uri'

class Result < ActiveRecord::Base


  def self.raw_results
   raw_xml = open("https://s3.amazonaws.com/...")
   document = Nokogiri::XML(raw_xml)
   articulos = document.css('ARTICULOS')
   articulos.each do |result|
     patient = result.css('nombre_paciente').first.content
     gender = result.css('Sexo').first.content
     Result.create!(patient: patient, gender: gender)
   end
  end
end
```

XML

```
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8093365
```

Comment: paste your XML please

Comment: Any validations on `Result`?

Comment: Hitham S. AlQadheeb no, I have yet not set any validation.

Comment: `document` is an empty Nokogiri XML object. Nokogiri isn't parsing the file you point to (I tried and it didn't work)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to update the variable names

```
 name= result.css('name').first.content
 gender = result.css('gender').first.content

 Result.create(name: name, gender: gender)
```